# Loading Data into MySQL using Load Data Infile

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

I am trying to test using a .txt file to load data into a table that I have created.

My text file looks like this:

`Facebook Inc.  FB
 Apple Inc. AAPL
 Intel Corp.    INTC`

It is formatted with a tab in between the fields then I hit enter to go to next line for the next row to insert.

I'm using the following query in PHP to do so:

`$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'company.txt' INTO TABLE Company;";`

It insert the data from the file that I have sitting on the webserver, however when it I check the data in the table it is chopping off the last character on AAPL and INTC like so:
[image]

Is the command wrong or am I formatting the txt file incorrectly to insert this data?

Comment: symbol is varchar(4)?

Comment: @Zack In case you don't understand what IdontDownVote is telling you.  Go to phpMyAdmin and have a look at the Structure of your table.  What is the data type of the `symbol` column?  Many of us are predicting that the data type is `VARCHAR(3)` which means it will only retain the first 3 characters of whatever is passed to it.  This is the most likely cause of the truncation.  If your column data type is not `VARCHAR(3)` please express that in your question.

Comment: That was the issue! Could have sworn I typed `symbol varchar(8)`